# jquery load() fragment url variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, fragment

I have created some jQuery code to asynchronously load content for my website, but I'm unable to get just the fragment to display.  This is because I am using variables to contain the URLs.  How can I load the page fragment for #page-content, while passing in the url variable?

jQuery code:

```
$('.level2 a, level3 a, level4, a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#page-content').load(this.href '#page-content'); //pages finished loading
}); //clicked on nav
```

Obviously, what I'm getting is the load() version without the fragment specified within the selector, as documented on the jQuery API.  How can I prepend the url to the selector when + will only make jQuery think it's the non-fragment version?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#page-content').load(this.href '#page-content');
```

Should be

```
$('#page-content').load(this.href + ' #page-content');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#page-content').load(this.href '#page-content');
```

should write as

```
$('#page-content').load(this.href +  ' #page-content');
                                      ^ -- need an space here
                                  ^ -- string join using +
```

Comment: Works!  Only now, only partial content is loading (it seems the related javascript isn't loading").  Does this mean I should use the $.ajax() method instead?

Comment: late comment but... once you start using jquery load with fragments it strips out scripts.